# Compiling rust iced example to wasm - image assets path

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

I want to compile one of the iced example to wasm, but it doesn't find image(ferris.png).
[Here's my code](https://github.com/wiktorkujawa/rust-wasm-template).

It has also package.json file with scripts to build and run page on localhost:3000(yarn build and yarn dev should be enough, but you can also run yarn build:debug and yarn dev).
The problem is in line 654 - 658 in main.rs file.

```
if cfg!(target_arch = "wasm32") {
            // image("/wasm-test/images/ferris.png")
            // image("wasm-test/images/ferris.png")
            // image("/images/ferris.png")
            image("images/ferris.png")
}
```